# Modify global variable with Pool in multiprocessing module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm not familiar with multiprocessing module. I am tring to verify that variables in different processes are irrelevant. After the test, I find different processes probably "share" variables. That happens when process has the same pid. I am not sure if there is some relationship?

Environment : Windows 10 ; python 3.7

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

p=0

def Child_process(id_number):
    global p
    print('Task start: %s(%s)' % (id_number, os.getpid()))
    print('p = %d' % p)
    p=p+1
    print('Task {} end'.format(id_number))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(4)
    p.map(Child_process,range(5))
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

The result is:
Task start: 0(7668)
p = 0
Task start: 1(10384)
Task 0 end
p = 0
Task start: 2(7668)
p = 1
Task 1 end
Task 2 end
Task start: 3(7668)
Task start: 4(10384)
p = 1
Task 4 end
p = 2
Task 3 end

I think the p should always be 0, but it increases when different processes have the same pid?

Comment: @Green Cloak Guy I get it. Thank you

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy: This isn't PID reuse. This is a pool of four long-lived processes, where a single process performs multiple tasks; it's not forking a new process for each task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a thread/process pool will re-use the same thread/process.  This lets you setup resources in the when the thread/process  starts so that each thread/process won't have to initialize them each time.  This includes global variables, open files, sockets, etc.  You can do the one time initialization by passing an `initializer` function to the thread/process.  So if you set or increment the variable `p` it will remain set throughout the various runs of the process.  If you want the variable to always start at 0 for each run, you'll need to set it to 0 at the start of each run.

This note is in the [multiprocessing.pool.Pool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) class:

> Note: Worker processes within a Pool typically live for the complete duration of the Pool’s work queue. A frequent pattern found in other systems (such as Apache, mod_wsgi, etc) to free resources held by workers is to allow a worker within a pool to complete only a set amount of work before being exiting, being cleaned up and a new process spawned to replace the old one. The maxtasksperchild argument to the Pool exposes this ability to the end user.

Comment: Sorry, I am still not very clear. 
1.So if I don't specify the maxtasksperchild argument, the process will re-use the resource the same process set before?
2."By definition, a thread/process pool will re-use the same thread/process. " What's the definition of same process?
3.Why not each process in my example use the same resource like global variables p? But there are 3 processes use the same variable p and the other 2 use another same variable p.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: As it looks there are only 2 processes actually. So that explains it. I would reccomend also printing the pid in the print of p @huangjl.

Comment: @Tomerikoo I have already understood that one processes may re-use another process's resource. But I am not sure when  will the process re-use the other process, and I guess that happen when they run the same function? And why there only two processes, not three, four... Is that random? Thank you!

Comment: Your code initializes the pool with 4 processes (`Pool(4)`).  Which of the 4 processes are used isn't really defined.  Since the function you run is rather short, the first process probably finished very quickly and hence was reused instead of the 3rd process.

Comment: To understand thread/process pools you might want to see this Wikipeia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool.  A process cannot re-use another process's resource but a single process can run the same function multiple times.  In your case the process with the PID=7668 runs the function `Child_process` 3 times and the process with the PID=10384 runs the function `Child_process`  twice.